# Numeral prefixes of tidal constituents

Tags: time, latin, prefixes, greek

If tidal constituents with frequencies of one, two, three, and four cycles per day (respectively, periods of one, a half, a third, and a fourth of a day) were to be termed systematically based on [numeral prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_prefix), would any of the following sets be internally inconsistent:

1. diurnal, dudiurnal, tridiurnal, quadridiurnal (Latin cardinal)
2. diurnal, bidiurnal, terdiurnal, quaterdiurnal (Latin multiples)
3. diurnal, duodiurnal, tridiurnal, tetradiurnal (Greek cardinal)
4. diurnal, diplodiurnal, triplodiurnal, tetrapodiurnal (Greek multiples)
5. diurnal, half-diurnal, third-diurnal, fourth-diurnal (English fractions)
6. diurnal, semidiurnal, trientdiurnal, quadrantdiurnal (Latin fractions)
7. diurnal, hemidiurnal, tritodiurnal, tetartodiurnal (Greek fractions)

So far I've only found inconsistent sets, even in authoritative texts:

- diurnal, semidiurnal, third-diurnal, quarter-diurnal [2](https://iho.int/mtg_docs/com_wg/IHOTC/IHOTC_Misc/TWCWG_Constituent_list.pdf)
- diurnal, semidiurnal, terdiurnal, quarter-diurnal [3](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=78bE5U7TVuIC&lpg=PP1&dq=names%20of%20tidal%20constituents&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- diurnal, semidiurnal, third-diurnal, fourth-diurnal [4](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=QiBGAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&vq=quater&dq=%22third-diurnal%22&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- diurnal, semidiurnal, terdiurnal, quaterdiurnal [5](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=GcXrCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA8&ots=NhbvcSe4Ed&dq=diurnal%2C%20bidiurnal%2C%20terdiurnal%2C%20quaterdiurnal&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q&f=false)

The inconsistency arises from: mixing Latin, Greek, or English prefixes; and mixing the half-day period with the two-cycle per day frequency.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with inconsistent prefixes? We use *triangles, quadrilaterals*  and *pentagons*, from Latin and Greek.  I don't see anybody calling for us to use *quintalateral* or *tetragon*.

Comment: The next question then is: which inconsistent set should be adopted -- for example, in Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_tides#Tidal_constituents

Comment: Surely you want a set of words that are easily understood, not necessarily etymologically consistent?